# Setting the Input Value attribute to a variable with space.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the value of a input button to a string variable.i.e"A Guide to the School Bus"; But when the HTML loads up only the first word comes up in the button. My code is given below. Thanks for the help.

```
var title="A Guide to the School Bus";
var htmlString= "<div class="+title+ ">"+"<input type="+"button  "+"value="+title+"  onclick=loadBook()>"+"</div>";
$(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint);
```

And the attachpoint is a reference in the HTML that i got using the following.

```
var attachpoint=document.querySelector('.buttonAttachPoint');
```

Comment: The Button just show "A".

Comment: You could attach your handler rather than put an "onclick" inline: `$(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint).click(loadBook)`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is because you're not putting quotes around the attribute values. Try this:

```
var htmlString= '<div class="'+title+'"><input type="button" value="'+title+'"  onclick="loadBook()"></div>';
```

You can either escape all the `"` in your string or, like I have done, just switch between `'` and `"`. `"` will show up as a normal character and `'` is used to mark the start and finish of strings.

As a side point you probably wouldn't want to put the variable `title` as the `class` on the `div` as it would add each separate word as a class, so in your example the div would have 6 classes added to it.